# how to generate executable when i have all the files in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, nokia

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/network-broadcastsender.html

ths example give me all the files but how to make an executable from this? please tell assuming a know nothing at all

Comment: Which OS are you on? And do you have any IDE installed? Do you have a .pro file with this project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Qt Application Framework http://qt.nokia.com/downloads
2. Install it, and select to additionally install all examples.
3. Run Qt Creator and when it opens look for "Getting Started" tab in "Welcome" tab.
4. On "Getting Started" tab look for "Show Examples and Demos" at the bottom. Check it and in search field search for the name of the example.
5. Click on example and then follow the wizard to create new project.
6. Click on the green triangle on bottom left to compile and run it.